# Error: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in '/node_modules/raw-body'

Tags: node.js

```
WARNING  Compiled with 3 warnings                                                                 

warning  in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js

Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

warning  in ./node_modules/on-finished/index.js

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in '/node_modules/on-finished'

warning  in ./node_modules/raw-body/index.js

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in '/node_modules/raw-body'
```

I got this error while I am working on my Vue.js project. I tried to reinstall the node modules, update npm and recompile, but it still shows this error. What else can I do?

My versions:

- raw-body: 2.5.1
- node: 16.13.1
- npm: 8.13.2

Edit: Problem solved, imported something extra from express that is automatically inserted by VS code

Comment: What extra thing did you import? I'm having the same issue and am not sure how to resolve it

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue and I have and extra import on my router/index.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import routes from "./routes";
import store from "../store/index";
import { query } from "express";  This import generate the issue

Vue.use(Router);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34617358)